# Корзина покупок в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Изучаю ASP.Net Core и никак не могу найти, как правильно реализовать корзину с помощью этой технологии. 
Пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в куках и сессиях, но я так понял, что нужно получить идентификатор сессии, как-то его хранить в куках, чтобы потом получать по нему данные корзины даже после закрытия, если пользователь не авторизован. Так как авторизации пока у меня нет, то хочу реализовать именно без авторизации.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне получить этот самый идентификатор пользователя или сессии, чтобы он не пропал, хранился в БД и по нему можно было бы получать эти самые товары.

Comment: пришел пользователь на сайт. Как только он добавляет товар в корзину, генерируешь guid, ставишь ему в куки. В бд в таблице Carts, PK будет как раз таки этот guid пользователя. Любые изменения пользователя будут менять данные по корзине с этим гуид. соответственно когда пользователь приходит на сайт, пытаешься из куки достать этот идентификатор и смотришь, если такая есть - то достаешь товары с корзины и показываешь ему.

Comment: @SultanovShamil спасибо большое! А сессии вообще не применяются тогда?

Comment: ну гуид в куки и будет твоей сессией.